# What is #auto attribute here and why it is required

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms

I am trying to learn angular material 2 and came across this `#auto` attribute in autocomplete.I understand `auto` can be replaced with any text, but why there need a `#` here before `auto` and what is there any name of this attribute?

```
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput placeholder="State" [mdAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
</md-input-container>

<md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete">
               ^^^^ what is name of this property
  <md-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state">
    {{ state }}
  </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It is a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-) that allows us to get reference to html element or something else if we declare directive on this element.

**We can declare template reference variable via** (1)

- `#var`
- `ref-var`

### #Default behavior

In most cases, **Angular sets the reference variable's value to the html element on which it was declared** (2) .

```
<div #divElem></div>
<input #inputEl>
<table #tableEl></table>
<form #formEl></form>
```

In the preceding all template reference variables will refer to the corresponding elements.

```
#divElem     HTMLDivElement
#inputEl     HTMLInputElement
#tableEl     HTMLTableElement
#formEl      HTMLFormElement
```

---

### #Directives can change default behavior

But a directive can change that behavior and set the value to something else, such as itself.

**Angular assigns references with empty value to component** (3)

If we have component like:

```
@Component({
  selector: '[comp]',
  ...
})
export class SomeComponent {}
```

and template as:

```
<div comp #someComp></div>
```

then `#someComp` variable will refer to component itself (`SomeComponent instance`).

**Angular doesn't locate directives in references with empty value** (4)

If we change `@Component` decorator to `@Directive`

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[comp]',
  ...
})
export class SomeDirective {}
```

then `#someComp` variable will refer to `HTMLDivElement`.

*How we can get `SomeDirective` instance in this case?*

Fortunately, **Template reference variable can have value** (5)

- `#var="exportAsValue"`
- `ref-var="exportAsValue"`

**We can define `exportAs` property within `@Component/@Directive` decorator** (6):

> **exportAs** is a name under which the component instance is exported in a
>   template. Can be given a single name or a comma-delimited list of
>   names.

```typescript
@Directive({
  selector: '[comp]',
  exportAs: 'someDir',
  ...
})
export class SomeDirective {}
```

and then use **`exportAs` value as value for template reference variable within template** (7):

```typescript
<div comp #someComp="someDir"></div>
```

After that `#someComp` will refer to our directive.

Now let's imagine we have several directives applied to this component. And we want to get specific directive instance.`exportAs` property is a good choice to solve this problem.

---

Let's go back to your code

If you open source code of `MdAutocomplete` component you can see:

```typescript
@Component({
  ...
  exportAs: 'mdAutocomplete'
})
export class MdAutocomplete {
  ...
```

Since in your template you have

`#auto="mdAutocomplete"`

Then `#auto` variable will refer to instance of `MdAutocomplete` component. This reference is used in `MdAutocompleteTrigger` directive:

```typescript
@Directive({
  selector: 'input[mdAutocomplete], input[matAutocomplete],' +
            'textarea[mdAutocomplete], textarea[matAutocomplete]',
  ...
})
export class MdAutocompleteTrigger implements ControlValueAccessor, OnDestroy {
  @Input('mdAutocomplete') autocomplete: MdAutocomplete;
```

because you're passing `auto` variable to input within template

```typescript
<input mdInput placeholder="State" [mdAutocomplete]="auto"
```

We can omit value and use only variable name in this case like

```typescript
<md-autocomplete #auto>
```

but

- assignment value to value of `exportAs` property precisely indicates us where to get the instance.
- if `md-autocomplete` is a directive then `auto` variable will refer to `HTMLElement`.

So prefer specifying value for template reference variable if you doubt what it will refer to.

Comment: Updated link: https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables