# Angular 2 getting an element ref for function

Tags: angular

Can I get the `ElementRef` from `doWidth()`?

```
<div [style.left.px]="doWidth(maybeThisElementRef)">
</div>
```

Rather than turning the div into a component?

Comment: maybe, do you have a link to what #el does?

Comment: wunderbar danke

Answer (score 2):

Just use template reference variable like:

```
<div #el [style.left.px]="doWidth(el)">
```

See also

- [What is #auto attribute here and why it is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45250259/what-is-auto-attribute-here-and-why-it-is-required)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to yurzui's answer, you can also reference it in your components as this:

```
<div #el [style.left.px]="doWidth()">


  import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
  ....
  @ViewChild('el') private el;
  ...
  doWidth(){
    this.el.value="blabla" //or something else 
  }
```