# Angular 2: No UI Slider - How to change color?

Tags: angular, colors, nouislider

I'm using ng2-nouislider in my angular 2 app

I trying to change the color between the slider handles by following this example: [section-colored-connect](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/examples/#section-colored-connect)

In my HTML I've

```
<nouislider #slider [config]="someKeyboardConfig"></nouislider>
```

and in .ts

```
@ViewChild('slider') slider;

  someKeyboardConfig: any = {
    behaviour: 'drag',
    connect: [true, true, true, true, true],
    start: [20, 40, 60, 80],
    keyboard: true,  // same as [keyboard]="true"
    step: 0.1,
    pageSteps: 10,  // number of page steps, defaults to 10
    range: {
      min: 0,
      max: 100
    },
    pips: {
      mode: 'count',
      density: 2,
      values: 6,
      stepped: true
    }
  };
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.func();
  }

  func() {
    var connect = this.slider.querySelectorAll('.noUi-connect');
    var classes = ['c-1-color', 'c-2-color', 'c-3-color', 'c-4-color', 'c-5-color'];
    console.log(connect.length);
    for ( var i = 0; i < connect.length; i++ ) {
      connect[i].classList.add(classes[i]);
    }
  }
```

styles.css

```
.c-1-color { background: red; }
.c-2-color { background: yellow; }
.c-3-color { background: green; }
.c-4-color { background: blue; }
.c-5-color { background: purple; }
```

but it's not working. What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit:**

I see error in console

```
ERROR TypeError: this.slider.querySelectorAll is not a function
    at VitalSettingsComponent.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/vitals/vital-settings/vital-settings.component.ts.VitalSettingsComponent.func (vital-settings.component.ts:98)
    at VitalSettingsComponent.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/vitals/vital-settings/vital-settings.component.ts.VitalSettingsComponent.ngAfterViewInit (vital-settings.component.ts:62)
    at callProviderLifecycles (core.es5.js:11182)
    at callElementProvidersLifecycles (core.es5.js:11157)
    at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (core.es5.js:11141)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12246)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12603)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.es5.js:12561)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12239)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12603)
```

Comment: where you are adding colors that not seen it in the UI?

Comment: see func(). I'm adding classes there. Also I've edit my post and included the styles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A template reference variable like `#name` set on the component element will give us component instance (`NouisliderComponent` in your case).

If you want to get native element you have to specify `read` property for `@ViewChild` decorator:

```typescript
@ViewChild('slider', { read: ElementRef }) slider: ElementRef;
```

After that you will be able to use it like

<s>this.slider.querySelectorAll('.noUi-connect');</s>:

```typescript
this.slider.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.noUi-connect')
```

You can also try it in the corresponding **[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/bXDPt2CAqNvO8IJsMn4T?p=preview)**

This question might be also helpful

- [What is #auto attribute here and why it is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45250259/what-is-auto-attribute-here-and-why-it-is-required)

Comment: I've posted another question on nouislider. Do you think you can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45526114/angular-2-nouislider-how-to-recreate-the-slider