# angular 2 nouislider: How to recreate the slider?

Tags: angular, nouislider

I need to change the number of handles on a slider. When googling it says I need to destroy and create the slider again.

Now it says here: [Updating and reading slider options](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/more/#section-update) that:

> To update any other option, destroy the slider using
>   slider.noUiSlider.destroy() and create a new one. Note that events are
>   not unbound when destroying a slider.

I was able to destroy the slider:

```
@ViewChild('slider') slider;

destroySlider() {
    this.slider.slider.destroy();
}
```

but I can't seem to find how to create the slider in angular.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap slider in `EmbeddedView` via `*ngIf`

**component.html**

```html
<button (click)="reCreate()">Recreate slider</button>

<nouislider *ngIf="flag" #slider [config]="someKeyboardConfig"></nouislider>
```

and then reCreate function could look like:

**component.ts**

```typescript
flag = true;

reCreate() {
  this.slider.slider.destroy();
  this.flag = false;
  this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  this.flag = true;
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/bsaVydzv5xTxNYAUGQwr?p=preview)**

Comment: Works great. Thanks a lot.