# In this example why is the value of the template variable "ngModel"

Tags: angular

In this example, I see the explanation but im still not sure i understand why in this case the #name template variable is set to "ngModel".  What if there were 2 or 3 other input fields with template variables, would you also set their value to "ngModel"?

https://angular.io/guide/forms#show-and-hide-validation-error-messages

```
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"
       required
       [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="name"
       #name="ngModel">
<div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine"
     class="alert alert-danger">
  Name is required
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45250259/what-is-auto-attribute-here-and-why-it-is-required `exportAs is a name under which the component instance is exported in a template`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ngModel is the NgModel directive's selector which you need to set to activate it.  By setting #name="ngModel" you export the directive into the local variable with ngModel key.
And each input can have it's own export, i.e.

```
...
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"
       required
       [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="name"
       #name="ngModel">
...
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname"
       required
        [(ngModel)]="model.lastname" name="lastname"
        #lastname="ngModel">
```

Comment: Hi @Vega, what all features does the template reference variable provide when we assign ngModel to it? Example: touched, invalid, dirty, pristine. Any thing else?

Comment: @variable .value, .focus(), blur(), etc... anything that you would get for getElementbyId()

Comment: How to access these in the class file?

Comment: @variable There is '@ViewChild' property decorator

Comment: Ok or we can also pass it via click even am I right?

Comment: Do you mean something like: "...(click)='doSomethingWith(myVariable.value)'"? Then yes

Comment: Thank you. Or even (click)=doSomethingWith(myVariable) and then in the class access myVariable.value... I am new to all this. Thanks.

Comment: @variable yw :)