# How to open mat-menu programmatically?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

Im trying to trigger opening a menu when clicking mat-nav-list item.

**HTML**

```
<mat-nav-list>
    <mat-list-item (click)="onOpenMenu(menu)" *ngFor="let i of data">
        <div mat-line>
            {{ i.name }}
        </div>
        <p mat-line>
            {{ i.email }}
        </p>
        <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
            <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </mat-list-item>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
        <button mat-menu-item>View profile</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Add contact</button>
    </mat-menu>
</mat-nav-list>
```

**TS**

```
onOpenMenu(menu: any): void {
   // menu doesn't have any openMenu() function 
   // which is of course not a trigger object but a menu itself.
   console.log(menu);
}
```

I have been trying to look at this [issue on github](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/2421) which is closer to my situation. but in my case i have a dynamic list of items which i wanted to open a menu every click.

<kbd>[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-list-nav-menu-item?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html)</kbd>

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You need to get hold of `MatMenuTrigger` instance from `[matMenuTriggerFor]` element

```
#menuTrigger="matMenuTrigger"  [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"
```

where

- `#menuTrigger` is the template reference variable
- `matMenuTrigger` is `exportAs` property of `MatMenuTrigger` metadata

and then simply call

```
(click)="menuTrigger.openMenu()"
```

**[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-list-nav-menu-item-jnjdxb?file=app/app.component.html)**

Read more about template reference variable here

- [What is #auto attribute here and why it is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45250259/what-is-auto-attribute-here-and-why-it-is-required/45251464#45251464)

Comment: @yurzui What happens if the menu button is shown only on hover of the menu item? Does the menu still work?

Comment: In my own implementation i get a openMenu is not defined.Its because the menu button is displayed with an ng-if on hover of the menu item

Comment: @KHAN Can you reproduce it in stackblitz?

Comment: Ye i will, please check back later.

Comment: @yurzui Here https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-list-nav-menu-item-t85phh?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: The menu button only displays on hover of the specific item. But now the menu dropdown does not work because it thinks its undefined due to the ngif and mouseleaving the item.

Comment: @KHAN Mouseleave event is firing when you open menu. That's because material creates overlay and you loose focus. Workaroung something like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-list-nav-menu-item-dzfmvc?file=app/app.component.html but i would rather use css display none for this case

Comment: I have a question aobut this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47370434/angular-5-on-mouse-enter-show-a-button-and-on-mouse-leave-hide-a-button?noredirect=1#comment81695749_47370434  If you want to add your display none solution instead that would be nice

Comment: how is this done from another component.  Component A (a modal) triggers this popup in Component B. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 22):

You can also control the `<mat-menu>` directly in the code.
Here is an example:

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatMenuTrigger } from '@angular/material/menu';

...
export class LanguageComponent {
  @ViewChild('languageMenuTrigger') languageMenuTrigger: MatMenuTrigger;
  
  ...

  openMenu() {
    this.languageMenuTrigger.openMenu();
  }
  
  closeMenu() {
    this.languageMenuTrigger.closeMenu();
  }
}
```

```html
<button
  mat-button
  [matMenuTriggerFor]="languageMenu"
  #languageMenuTrigger="matMenuTrigger">
  Language
  <mat-icon>expand_more</mat-icon>
</button>
<mat-menu #languageMenu="matMenu">
  <button
    mat-menu-item>
    English
  </button>
  <button
    mat-menu-item>
    Français
  </button>
</mat-menu>
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to completely control it programmatically, without having an element on your website that also controls the menu, you can declare an element containing `[matMenuTriggerFor]`, but hiding it via CSS.

Caveat: You will have to manually position the menu. You can do it roughly like that:

**Template:**

```
<div #menuTrigger [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" class="menu-trigger">I will be hidden</div>
<mat-menu #menu class="your-menu-class">
...
</mat-menu>
```

**CSS:**

```
.menu-trigger {
  display: none;
}
```

**Component:**

```
class YourComponent {
  @ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger) menuTrigger: MatMenuTrigger | undefined;

  constructor(private readonly viewRef: ViewContainerRef) { }

  someMethod() {
    this.menuTrigger?.menuOpened.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(() => {
      const menu = document.getElementsByClassName('your-menu-class')[0] as HTMLElement;
      const position: DOMRect = this.viewRef.element.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();

      menu.style.position = 'absolute';
      menu.style.top = `${position.top}px`;
      menu.style.left = `${position.width}px`;
    });

    this.menuTrigger?.openMenu();
  }
}
```

Comment: But... this is WITH an element "on your website"... although it is hidden it is still in the DOM and thus not completely programatically unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```html
<div (click)="openMenu()"> clike open menu</div>
<span [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" class="menu-trigger"></span>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false">
    <div mat-menu-item>a</div>
    <div mat-menu-item>b</div>
    <div mat-menu-item>c</div>
</mat-menu>
```

**TS**

```js
openMenu() {
    const menu = document.querySelector('.menu-trigger')
    menu.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'))
}
```

Now you can put openMenu on anywhere.

Comment: Yes, This is perfect and this is the only solution when working with setTimeout to trigger the click event other solutions have a click event with that menu trigger two times when clicked and manually by matMenu.