# @viewchild for directive always return element ref instead of directive reference- angular5

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-directive

I am currently working on a project where I need to pass some @input values based on component. So, that the directive will work accordingly. But the problem is I couldn't get reference of that directive. Instead I only got the elementRef in return. Please refer the below stackblitz sample for more reference.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-feptw3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are to ways to fix it:

1) Using `read` option:

```
@ViewChild("myCustomDir", { read: MyCustomDirective}) myCustomDir: MyCustomDirective;
```

**[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xze5j3?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)**

See also:

- [How to get reference of the component associated with ElementRef in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39908967/how-to-get-reference-of-the-component-associated-with-elementref-in-angular-2/39909203#39909203)

2) Using `exportAs`

**directive.ts**

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[myCustom]",
  exportAs: 'myCustom'
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
})
export class MyCustomDirective {
  ...
}
```

**html**

```
<h1 myCustom #myCustomDir="myCustom">
                           ^^^^^^^^
```

**[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rron1d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)**

See also:

- [What is #auto attribute here and why it is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45250259/what-is-auto-attribute-here-and-why-it-is-required)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. It works. Thank you so much.