# What is the difference between #someId="someName" and only #someId in an Angular template?

Tags: angular

From the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/cheatsheet):

```
<video #movieplayer ...>
<button (click)="movieplayer.play()">
</video>
```

> Creates a local variable movieplayer that provides access to the video element instance in data-binding and event-binding expressions in the current template.

Which I can understand, but I sometimes see the following notation in Angular Material components:

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu"> <!-- What does "matMenu" mean here? --> 
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

I don't understand what the **"matMenu"** is used for? The [example from Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview) works well without it.

Comment: Read from `Fortunately, Template reference variable can have value (5)` in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45250259/what-is-auto-attribute-here-and-why-it-is-required#answer-45251464